# Let $u(x, t)$ be the solution to the initial-boundary value problem of the wave equation, find $u(3,3)$ and $u(4,4)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let $u(x, t)$ be the solution to the initial-boundary value problem of the
wave equation for x, t > 0:
$u_{tt} = 4u_{xx}, u_x(0, t) = 0, u(x, 0) = φ(x) = 2x − 1$ and
$u_t(x, 0) = ψ(x) = 2x$ if $x ∈ (2, 10)$ and $0$ if $x ∈ (0, 2] ∪ [10,∞)$.

So I know how to set this equation up using $u(x, t) = 1/2 [φ_{odd}(x + 2t) + φ_{odd}(x − 2t)] + 1/4 \int_{x-2t}^{x+2t} ψ_{odd}(s)ds$.

But I'm not sure on what to use in place of $ψ_{odd}(s)ds$, since the conditions there are mentioned. Like if I have an integral from 0 to 6, what am I supposed to do? Should I split it up into 2 integrals, one with 0 and 2, and the other with 2 and 6?

Comment: (1) If $u_x(0,t)=0$, you should use the *even* extension of $\varphi$ and $\psi$; (2) does the condition "if $x\in(2,10)$ and $0$ if $x\in(0,2]\cup[10,\infty)$" refer to $\varphi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, or only to $\psi(x)$?

Comment: Oh thank you! The condition refers only to $ψ(x)$

Comment: also how do even extensions work? even extensions just mean that there will be no negative sign outside the function if for $φ(x)$ x is less than 0, right?

Comment: The even extension of $\varphi$ is defined as
$$
\varphi_{even}(x)=\begin{cases}
\varphi(x)&\text{if $x\geq 0$}, \\
\varphi(-x)&\text{if $x<0$},
\end{cases}
$$
and similarly for the even extension of $\psi$.

Comment: thanks, so I don't make any changes in the equation even if x is less than 0 right? And was my theory of splitting the integral right for $ψ(x)$?

Comment: You can split the integral, by I don't understand why one with $0$ and $2$, and the other with $2$ and $6$. For instance, $u(3,3)$ is given by
$$
\frac{1}{2}[\varphi_{even}(3+6)+\varphi_{even}(3-6)]+\frac{1}{4}\int_{3-6}^{3+6}\psi_{even}(s)\,ds.
$$
Since $\psi_{even}$ has support in $(-10,-2)\cup(2,10)$, the integral is split as
$$
\int_{-3}^{-2}\psi_{even}(s)\,ds+\int_{2}^{9}\psi_{even}(s)\,ds.
$$

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding, but why does $ψ_{even}$ have support in $(-10,-2)$?

Comment: $x\in(-10,-2)\implies -x\in(2,10)$.